# Strange Linux file writing

Tags: php, linux, file, utf-8

I'm developing with PHP. I have only the following statements:

```
<?php
$text = "http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%86-%d9%be%db%8c%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86-2/";
$text = urldecode($text);
$log_file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
$text = substr($text, -100000);
@$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'OLD-ENCODING');
fwrite($log_file, $text);
fclose($log_file);
?>
```

Under Windows OS, the content of log file is as expected:

```
http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/این-پیکان-2/
```

But under Linux (CentOS) the output is:

```
http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/Ø§ÛŒÙ†-Ù¾ÛŒÚ©Ø§Ù†-2/
```

which is decoding wrong.

**Edit:** The script is ran by `Cron`. I don't know if this makes any difference.

**Edit:** I noticed that characters are displayed strange only when I open the file using the browser. When I download the file and open it in Windows everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Hope this will help you out. You should initiate a header defining charset as `utf-8` to get desired output. like this `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793528)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$s='http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%86-%d9%be%db%8c%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86-2/';
echo $s = urldecode($s);
```

**Output:** `http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/این-پیکان-2/`

**Solution 2:** `Not a good solution than first one`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793548)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
$s='http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%86-%d9%be%db%8c%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86-2/';
echo $s = urldecode($s);
```

**Whole code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$text = "http://www.aecinema.ir/movie/%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%86-%d9%be%db%8c%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86-2/";
$text = urldecode($text);
$log_file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
$text = substr($text, -100000);
fwrite($log_file, $text);
fclose($log_file);
```

Comment: Tried it. Same problem with no error. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Mowji Can you share your code which you are currently using?

Comment: Sorry. This was a Linux issue with files.

Comment: @Mowji, I dont think so, might be there is some issue with your linux.